# Компилятор выдает ошибку на метод append в python

Tags: python, pycharm, append

Доброе время суток! Столкнулся с такой проблемой - pycharm не хочет работать с методом append. Ну то есть он работает, но выдает ошибку по формату листа, можете подсказать как решить эту проблему... Ну как я понимаю скрины больше дадут информации чем я)[image: псевдокод]

[image: сама ошибка]

Comment: Пожалуйста добавляйте код в виде текста, а не в виде картинке. В виде текста его легче читать, его можно скопировать и по нему можно провести поиск.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7):

Первое: хватит называть **интерпретатор Python** компилятором

Второе, по теме:

У вас есть словарь `actual_post_id`, потом вы пишите:

```py
actual_post_id = actual_post_id["id"]
```

Получаете `id` типа `int` и записываете его в переменную, которая раньше являлась словарём. Так как Python динамически типизируемый язык - ему ничего не стоит сменить тип переменной.

А потом, вы забываете, что словаря больше нет, и для целого числа, которое теперь в переменой, вызываете `append`.

Отсюда и ошибка. Просто переименуйте переменную, чтобы не допускать перекрытия имён

Comment: Так и есть! Благодарю за подробное объяснение! И впредь не буду называть)

Comment: Точности ради: Python компилирует исходный код в промежуточное состояние - ассемблер и затем интерпретирует его. Так что это и компилятор тоже. Смотрите модуль `dis`.

Answer (score 5):

Pycharm тут не причём

Ошибка указывает на то, что объект типа `int` не имеет метода `append`.

Ошибка в коде заключается в том, что в свой строке `actucal_post_id.append(actucal_post_id)` вы пытаетесь добавить в объект `int` его же значение. Причем добавить так, как это делают со списками.

Это произошло потому что сначала вы объявляете `actucal_post_id` как список, а затем в цикле работаете с этим объектом, как с переменной.

Для решения проблемы измените название переменной, с которой работаете в цикле `for`

Comment: Благодарю! Именно в этом и напортачил!